# How form layout of user login page can be changed Drupal 7 without altering its tpl file ?

Tags: users

I want to change the layout of user login form in Drupal 7. I don't want to change or create its tpl file for that purpose. Is there any module which will works for me ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: I just want to re arrange positions of fields in user login form for  example now it is showing username , password , twitter and facebook button , what i want is twitter button , facebook button , username field , password field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). You have to change the `#weight` property of the form elements.

If you don't know what I'm talking about have a look at the FAPI [reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) and [quick start guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826).

Answer (score 0):

Have you check profile 2 that you can easy change from the admin user interface. Also download the follow module which works with profile 2. Also you can hook_form_alter as adviced above. I have written a tutorial about this process and I hope it helps http://whatisdrupal.info/drupal-module